# Can YouTube API quota increase be approved if request before API client launch?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Our initial request for an increased YouTube quota was not approved because:

*"Proposed use violates API Terms of Service, Policies, Documentations and/or Specifications. You can re-apply once the above concerns have been addressed."*

However, there is no further detail. We have contacted YouTube back and asked what specifically the issue or issues are, but since we thought we were in adherence we are a bit in the dark unfortunately. They haven't responded as yet and it has been some time since we responded asking for clarification so I am a little concerned.

The only thing we can see is that perhaps our issue is that we have applied before launch (terms do state *"If your API Client reaches the quota limit for a service, you can apply for a quota extension using this form"* in the terms), but with only 1m points per day, we will hit that very quickly indeed, so requesting the increase only once we are hitting it seems very risky indeed. Is this potentially the issue?

Any advice very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK and as I've experienced in other Google APIs, you need not wait to reach your current quota limits. As soon as you perceive that you'll reach your current quota limit or you're already close to reaching it, you may already send a quota increase request. Check [quota usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) to learn more.

On the other hand, note that all API requests, including invalid requests, incur at least a one-point quota cost. And, one possible reason that requests might not be granted is a high error rate on your project. So, to help lower your quota usage, I suggest that you consider the following:

- Implement [exponential backoff for error retries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/encoding-with-dash#retries-and-exponential-backoff). See sample code [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video#Sample_Code).
- Use [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) instead of polling.

Comment: Do you know what kind of quota limit there is for push notifications? I havn't been able to find this out.